# consume php soap webservice in winform c#

Tags: c#, php, winforms, web-services, soap

one of my friend made a soap webservice in PHP and now i have to consume it into my winform app. I added web Service Reference , pasted the URL and it is showing method name.

The method name is **Display()**.
Now after adding when write code on button click, it is showing following three methods:

```
 MyWebServiceName. DisplayCompletedEventArgs
                    DisplayCompletedEventHandler
                    SiteControllerService
```

There is no **soapClient** or direct Display method ,any one know , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe << MyWebServiceName ws = new MyWebServiceName(); ws.Display(); >> ??

Comment: no it is not showing ... even if i write  MyWebServiceName ws = new MyWebServiceName(); , it gives error that it is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' 
!!

Comment: Then MyWebServiceName is a namespace. Must be there a type inside this namespace that represents the client proxy.

Comment: I bet for SiteControllerService...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the WSDLyou must have in the VS project. You will find the service name:

Ex:

```
<wsdl:service name="SiteControllerService">
```

So you must type:

```
MyWebServiceName.SiteControllerService SOAPclient = new MyWebServiceName.SiteControllerService(); 
SOAPClient.Display();
```

Visual Strudio create a namespace to encapsulate all classes generated to work with the web service. In that namespace you will find the soap proxy client, events and events handler and any data transfer object needed to pass parameters to proxy client or to recive the response.

Comment: yes already solved it.. pretty dumb question i asked , sorry & Thanks